# OutOfMemoryError while converting Stream to String in Android

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, bufferedreader

am loading xml file from Assets folder. am getting OutOfMemoryError.
The code which i have used is

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {  
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NEW_LINE);
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //do nothing.
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //do nothing.    
        }
    }
    reader=null;
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Is there an alternate way to get rid of this Exception.
It will be more helpful if you post any code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may read one line from the XML file, process it, and continue to the next line. Don't read the whole file into memory, the file may be very large.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to parse a big Xml using a String. You should turn to a streaming version of the parser. Google Http Java Client proposes such a library : http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client

Answer (score 0):

put line=null; in while loop after appending to sb.

Comment: and sorry to put this as answer because i can not comment at other's post.

Answer (score 0):

try Below

Have you tried the built in method to convert a stream to a string? It's part of the Apache Commons library (org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils).

Then your code would be this one line:

**String total = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);**

The documentation for it can be found here: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream%29

The Apache Commons IO library can be downloaded from here: http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi

Comment: Can you guide me how to use this one? am little bit confused.

Comment: you have to Add External Library